Sign up/in by via federated identity provider that uses spaces
Description:
We provide a B2B service. One of our clients is the Foo Company. The expectation is that their users should have access to our service but only after signing into their system. (So it should work like login via Facebook or Google). The users are synchronized with us upfront via SCIM protocol.
Solution:
To solve this we use Federated identity provider sign-in functionality from Cognito Pool. Both Authorization Servers (ours and theirs) are connected via an OIDC protocol.
Our solution works already on DEV & TEST.
We synchronize users and create them upfront in Cognito.
Then the user on our login page has an option "Login via Foo Company".
When logs in that way we link such a person with a previously created account.
It works.
But...
Problem:
It occurred that the PRODUCTION works in the Foo Company differently. On PRODUCTION they use white spaces in usernames which is prohibited in Cognito.
The process does not work as users with whitespaces cannot be created.
Any change in Foo Company is not possible. Only our part can be touched.
Question:
Is it possible and if yes how to handle such users with white spaces?
Part of our code that is responsible for linking users between IDPs looks like this below:
var destinationUser = 
   ProviderUserIdentifierType
      .builder()
      .providerName("Cognito")
      .providerAttributeValue(adminCreateUserResponse.user()
                                                     .username())
                                                     .build();
    
var sourceUser = ProviderUserIdentifierType
      .builder()
      .providerName(provider)
      .providerAttributeName("custom:external_id")                                         
      .providerAttributeValue(userResource.getExternalId())
      .build();

cognitoClient.adminLinkProviderForUser(AdminLinkProviderForUserRequest.builder()                                                                          
             .userPoolId(authorizationServerProperties.userPoolId()) 
             .destinationUser(destinationUser) 
             .sourceUser(sourceUser)
             .build());

The attribute mapping set on User Pool is following:

It seems the problem is when the user logs in. In such a case, our IDP (Cognito) communicates with their IDP (some commercial non-opensource) and receives data based on which tries to link an existing account. But those whitespaces break everything.
I can remove whitespaces from usernames on our end in the above "linking part" code. But still how to inject into communication between Cognito and external IDP flow? Should it be solved via Lambda triggers from User pool properties?
